# PayPal Here integration with online Paypal button

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, integration, store

I want to be able to take an online order in a store to have the item shipped to the consumers home if the item is out of stock in store. We currently use PayPal on our website. I want to be able to use an iPad to place an order and take payment for an online order via PayPal here with a  credit card. Is this possible? Can I get PayPal here to integrate with PayPal on the website?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you.  If you want to take credit cards on the website you should use Payments Pro.  Have you looked into that?